# Cannot install Robot Operating System in Debian 11.2.0 after following official documentation

Tags: debian, ros

I need to install Robot Operating System on my Debian Virtualbox instance for school. I followed [the official docs](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html). The first obstacle I found was when I needed to run `sudo add-apt-repository universe` which returned `Error: 'universe' is invalid`. Fortunately [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227760/error-multiverse-invalid-error-universe-invalid) solved that problem.

However a few steps later there is a problem. I ran `sudo apt update` but it says `Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list (Component)`, so I checked the file with nano. These are the contents:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu main
```

I don't know what exactly is the malformed part. I deleted the ones within square brackets and it still returns the same error. There was a post I read that told me to delete the offending file, but it's of no use as installing `ros-rolling-desktop` will fail because packages.ros.org is deleted. So far I am stuck and I'm out of ideas.

It's a shame they didn't put more care into their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I used to facing this problem though my system is Ubuntu 18.04, I think of these questions may have universal solution.
As for my method,I tried many ways to solve it but I can't remember which way can run.
Method：
1.try this：
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
if you can't install this then try to search on this web:
[https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu，](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu%EF%BC%8C) then try to download.

2.(I don't know this way should be OK)
`cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`
`sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`
check it row by row, add a 'space' fore the signal '$' which seems to be
' $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null'

if it can't run correctly,please return it.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with the link, it's broken. Do you want me to download Docker? It seems to have nothing to do with the installation process I'm doing.
I've listed the entire contents of the ros source file, there isn't a single signal $.